# 'Signal' as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

My dictionary lists the word 'signal' as an adjective, apart from its usual usage as a noun. Could someone provide me with examples for such a usage? Also, how popular is such an adjective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means ‘notable, conspicuous; remarkable, striking’ and is in current, if not frequent, use. The OED’s most recent citation, dated 2000, is from the ‘New York Book Review’:

> This gathering of data is a signal achievement.

Comment: Between them, *"signal achievement"* and *"signal accomplishment"* have about 10,000 instances in Google Books for the past century. Not exactly "common" in such a vast corpus", but certainly not all that "rare" either.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/on-being-left-low-and-dry-temperance-weighs-heavy-this-poll-season-competitive-prohibitionism-is-in-the-air/)

> Wherever and whenever it has been tried – including in the ultimate totalitarianism of Stalin’s Soviet Union – prohibition has proved to be a **signal failure**, causing not just sizeable revenue loss to the exchequer but also giving rise to an entrenched bootlegging mafia.